# Getting CORS error when I embed my Zoho Catalyst Application as an iframe in Zoho CRM

Tags: catalystbyzoho, catalystcloudscale, zohocatalyst, catalystappsail

I tried creating a new widget in Zoho CRM where I embedded my Zoho Catalyst Application as an iFrame. But I am keep getting the following error:

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYGss.png)

Access to fetch at 'https://xyz.development.catalystappsail.com/' from origin 'https://crm.zoho.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.